# How to conver this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have function $x^2y+xy^2=2$

Help me to make $y = f(x)$ ?

I get only $xy(x+y) = 2$ and $y(x^2+xy)=2$

Comment: Solve $$x\cdot y^2+x^2\cdot y-2=0$$ for $y$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, $x \neq 0$.

Secondly, solve $x\cdot y^{2}+x^{2} \cdot y -2=0$. The determinant is $\Delta=x^{4}+8x$, so only when $x>0$ or $x\leq -2$ can this function be solved.

We can have $y=\frac{-x^{2}+\sqrt{x^{4}+8x}}{2x}$ or $y=\frac{-x^{2}-\sqrt{x^{4}+8x}}{2x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
solve the quadratic equation
$$
xy^2+x^2y-2=0
$$
with respect to $y$ and you have two possible functions.